# How to keep Azure AD sign-on parameters with ASP.NET subdomains

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure-active-directory

I'm implementing, to an existing ASP.NET web application, the authentication via Azure AD and OpenIdConnect. *All the packages version are listed at the end of the question*

The application correctly  contacts the Microsoft login service and the `id_token` is returned in the HTTP response, but when I try to access it inside the code with the `Request` structure, it appears to be `Nothing`.

*(In the image below, Request.Url is the action url used within the Microsoft service returned form)*

[image: Variable values control]

Going by exclusion in all the steps that the application performs, I think that the problem could be found in the URL structure generated by ASP.NET, in my case is `http://localhost:50725/CONNECTION_ID/HomePage.aspx`, where the `CONNECTION_ID` field is dynamic and reassigned for each connection.

Analyzing the HTTP packets, in fact, I find as a response to the sending of the token by Microsoft a "redirect" to the address linked to the user's connection, which, when loaded, loses the data related to authentication

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Object moved</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Object moved to <a href="http://localhost:50725/CONNECTION_ID/HomePage.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Based on other guides/answers and the Azure Application Registration form, I could not use any wildcards to define the return url for the authentication process.

How can I keep track of the authentication parameters to fully authenticate the user in my application?

**EDIT**

Debugging even more the code-flow I've found another issue, basically the Azure login procedure response triggers the `Session_start` event inside the `Global.asax`, therefore is creates a new Session.

The situation that I'm observing is the following:

1. The user opens the web application and tries the "Microsoft Login" option
2. The request is made to the login service
3. The `id_token` is passed via HTTP POST request back to the application, this triggers the `Application_BeginRequest` event inside the `Global.asax`
4. The request then triggers the `Session_start` event also from the `Global.asax` creating a new session and a new "base Url" for the current connection, therefore loosing track of the original session who called the authentication method and the `id_token` previously received

So, the real problem seems to be to keep the current session active and reload it with the authentication parameter provided by Microsoft

**PACKAGES VERSION**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same in our environment and it works fine.

To Authenticate Azure AD(Microsoft Identity) in asp.net application we need to provide app registration details in our `appsettings.json` in below format.

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb47",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx02",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

You need to add following Required packages , In my case `.csproj` as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApplication11-xxxx027-0xx2-xxA-xxD-D39xxx</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.1" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.1" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.16.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]
Here is my `program.cs` file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Add `AUTHORIZE` attribute in `homecontroller.cs` as below:
[image]
***SAMPLE OUTPUT FOR REFERNCE***:-
signin:
[image]
Successfully signout:
[image]

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***: [***Add sign-in to Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp)